# Show or Hide SSRS column based on specific parameter value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I am having trouble showing/hiding a column based on parameter value chosen.

How my report is set up:
Parameter:  ImportStatus  --ImportStatus parameter has three values you can choose from: M, V, E

If I choose ImportStatus value = 'M', then I want the report to display a specific column.

Currently, if I go to Column Visibility screen of a column I want to show/hide, I am able to hide column for all values instead of specific.  Any idea how to do this correctly?

My expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!ImportStatus.Value = "M",true,false)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
=IIF(Parameters!ImportStatus.Value = "M",true,false)
```

will give the same result as

```
=(Parameters!ImportStatus.Value = "M")
```

The expression you need to give specifies whether or not to **hide** the column, so to show a column where @ImportStatus = "M", you would simply reverse the logic:

```
=Not(Parameters!ImportStatus.Value = "M")
```